# The roots of a quadratic with a mistaken constant term are $-17$ and $15$; with a mistaken leading coefficient, $8$ and $-3$. Find the actual roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Loki and Unloki were independently solving the roots of a quadratic function. Loki got the roots $−17$ and $15$, while Unloki got the roots $8$ and $−3$. Loki realized he miscopied the constant term, while Unloki realized he miscopied the coefficient of the first degree term. What
>   are the actual roots of the quadratic function?

I've been thinking about this for a while, but I think I'm missing something.

From the first equation, the 2nd term is correct. It could be written as

$$x^2 + 2x + c$$

Then in the second equation, it can be written as

$$ax^2 -5x -24$$

then, taking the ratio $-5:2$, the equation should be

$$x^2 +2x + 48/5$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want $x^2+ax-24$ for your second equation.

Comment: why though, he miscopied the coefficient for the 2nd equation, so were not sure if the product of the roots is exactly -24 (?) sorry if im not seeing something

Comment: @SuperMage1 It seems you got the method, just repeat what youhave done for the first equation also for the second.

Comment: You know the roots he got, so you know the product of the roots he got.

Comment: I'm really sorry, i get that it is a(x^2-5x-24) then -5a = 2 right? then a = 2/-5? then we multiply that to the -24 term. which is 48/5..

Comment: Loki get $2ax$ right and Unloki gets $-24a$ correct, I think you can conlude form here.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

From the givens we know that

- Loki solved

$$a(x+17)(x-15)=0 \implies a(x^2+2x-17\cdot 15)=0$$

- Unloki solved

$$a(x-8)(x+3)=0\implies a(x^2-5x-8\cdot 3)=0$$